# Requesting help with Rhubarb error?

Tags: add-on

I have been following a Yogyog.org video on using Blender and Rhubarb to lipsync. It is titled "Free automated lipsync Blender, Makehuman + Rhubarb" if that matters.

Anyway

When I tried to run "Rhubarb lipsync" to sync the mouth movements to the text and wav files I uploaded I got the message in the image below.

(did I install Rhubarb incorrectly and how do I fix it, it looks like the error is worried about "locations' too but I am not sure what that means)
(the board said to give this a tag, so I chose addon, I couldn't find Rhubarb or lipsync, anyway, that is why I chose such a general descriptor)

[image]

Comment: While I hope somebody will be able to help you, this is more an issue with the specific add-on than with blender in general, so I would suggest posting an issue with the addon [here](https://github.com/scaredyfish/blender-rhubarb-lipsync/issues). You will probably get more help there.

Comment: Thank you. I created an account, read the suggested readings, my error code was different than those previously asked, so I asked the question. So I am on my way to a solution. Thanks again.